# Rename Files in a folder in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

Actually, I have focused my cursor Powershell in a particular folder, but I would like to rename all files contained in that folder so that each file is renamed like this:

filename.xml.traite => filename.xml

Indeed, I want to replace ".traite" by empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres what I would use:

```
Get-ChildItem | Foreach-Object{
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $_.Name.Replace("traite","")
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `.traite` instead of only `traite`

Comment: I used just `traite` and Windows was clever enough to remove the trailing `.`

Comment: ah nice didn't know that :)

Comment: Both of you are right. Thx a lot for your responses

Answer (score 0):

Or this, -whatif for testing.  Mostly any parameter you can pipe to can accept a scriptblock.  A missing second argument to -replace is assumed to be null.

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace '.traite' } -whatif

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\users\j\foo\filename.xml.traite Destination: C:\users\j\foo\filename.xml".
```